# Selecting from a list with unequal probabilities

Tags: probability-theory

Let $L=[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ be a  data  set.We need to choose one element such that the probability of $x_i$ is  $ p_i$.What methods are there that are algorithmically efficient to implement?  As an illustration, consider the following problem:

> We have an infinite collection of biased coins indexed by positive integers.The probability of the $ith$ coin being selected is $2^{-i}$ and the probability of  $ith$ coin landing up heads is $3^{-i}$ .A coin is chosen at  random . What is the probability that it lands up heads?

Here is my attempt at this particular problem:
Let's define the following  events:
$$A:\text{The coin lands up heads}$$
$$E_i: \text{ith coin is selected }.$$  Then,
$$P(A)=\sum_{i={i}}^{\infty}P(A/E_i)P(E_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}.\frac{1}{3^i}=\frac15$$The littile piece of pyhton code to numerically calculate the above probability is as under

[image]

Any suggestions /links/responses are highly appreciated.